# how to convert a string to date in MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, date

Now I have a data string like this `2002年05月11日`, I want to convert this string as a unix date timestamp, what should I do to convert this time? I have tried this way:

```
select STR_TO_DATE("2002年05月11日", "YYYY年MM月dd日")
```

did not work. Then I tried this:

```
select STR_TO_DATE("2002年05月11日", "%Y年%M月%d日")
```

still did not work. what should I do to convert it to date format that could understand by database?

Comment: Trivial inaccuracy. `%M` is not a pattern for 2-digit month number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use lower case 'm':

```
mysql> select STR_TO_DATE("2002年05月11日", "%Y年%m月%d日");
+-----------------------------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE("2002年05月11日", "%Y年%m月%d日")       |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
| 2002-05-11                                          |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
```